# Filling layer shapes with images based on filenames on QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, filling

I have a grid shaped layer. There is a special cadastral map image file for each grid name. The name of the image files is the same as the grid ids. There are thousands of images and layers available. Is there a method where I can fill each image to the relevant layer?

It's a little complicated. I leave an image for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible by going in to the grid symbology properties, and changing the fill type to Raster Image Fill [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlSsF.png). Then next to the box where you add a path to an image use the options button [2] and click Edit [3] to add an expression:

[image]

Then for the expression you concatenate the path to the image, then the image name field, and then the file extension of the image, something like this:

`'C:/xxxx/qgis testing/' || "Name" || '.png'`

---

*However...*

I am not sure that this is going to get you the result that you want. It sounds like you have a whole bunch of individual tiles that makes up a larger map that you would like to display. You also have the grid showing exactly where those tiles should be. I think you need to ask a different question which would be "I have a whole bunch of tiles, how do I georeference them in a batch using a grid", **or**, "how do I combine all of these tiles into a single layer". I think one of those would actually yield you a far better result.

Comment: I agree that tiling seems to be the way to go.